# On the set $\{n>0:\ n\ \text{is a quadratic nonresidue modulo the}\ n\text{th prime}\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

Let $S$ denote the set of positive integers $n$ with $n$ a quadratic nonresidue modulo the $n$th prime $p_n$. The first 20 elements of $S$ are
$$2,\, 3,\, 6,\, 7,\, 8,\, 10,\, 11,\, 13,\, 15,\, 18,\, 21,\, 24,\, 26, \,27,\, 28,\, 32,\, 33,\, 39, \,41,\, 44.$$
For more elements of $S$ see http://oeis.org/A332021.  I have the following natural conjecture.

**Conjecture.** The asymptotic density $d(S)$ of the set $S$ is $1/2$, that is,
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac{|\{n\in S:\ n\le N\}|}{N}=\frac12.\tag{1}$$

**QUESTION**. How to prove the conjecture? Is it practical to show that the set $S$ is infinite?

It seems that $(1)$ can be strengthened as follows: 
$$|\{n\in S:\ n\le x\}|=\frac x2+O(\sqrt x). \tag{2}$$

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: I suspect this conjecture is completely hopeless. The $n$-th prime function has no sensible arithmetic properties. Asking whether $n$ is a square mod $p_n$ is as good as a coin toss, so while we certainly would expect the density to be $1/2$, I doubt we have tools to prove it.

Comment: Agree, your question is weird, it suggests that you don't know "the $n$-th prime" has no direct meaning, we don't have any useful generating series for the function $n \to p_n$. Then, did you ever try to check a conjecture with the random model for the primes ? Here you'd need to check if extending the random model to take in account quadratic residues and $n\to p_{f(n)}$ has any chance to give non-contradictory results.

Comment: This conjecture appeals for studying the exact values of the prime-counting function.There are few results in this direction. For example, in my 2017 paper in Ramanujan J. , I proved that for any integer m>4 there is a positive integer n with π(mn)=m+n.